# Getting a TFrame owner to set TTabsheet caption

Tags: delphi

I have a TFrame with a TEdit component. The frames are created dynamically at runtime as a TTabsheet for a TPageControl. I need to set the TTabSheet.Caption to the TEdit.Text on the TEdits KeyPress method, but, how do I get the owner of the Frame so I can set the Caption?

```
procedure TKeywordFrame.KeywordNameEditKeyPress( Sender : TObject; var Key : Char );
  var
    AOwner : TComponent;

  begin
    if( ord( Key ) = VK_RETURN ) then
      begin
        AOwner := ?

        FKeywordListName := KeywordNameEdit.Text;
          with AOwner do
            begin
              Caption := KeywordNameEdit.Text;
            end;
      end;
  end;
```

I tried

```
AOwner := TKeywordFrame.Owner;
```

DPS.KeywordFrame.pas(272): E2233 Property 'Owner' inaccessible here

```
AOwner := TKeywordFrame.GetOwner();
```

DPS.KeywordFrame.pas(272): E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods or constructor

Maybe I am rummaging through the wrong haystack for a needle.

Comment: I gon't think that the _Owner_ is the right choice here. Iterate the _Parent_ until you reach the TabSheet.

Comment: Note that you trying to access Owner/GetOwner like it would be a class method. Use Self.Owner/Self.Parent (or simply Owner/Parent) instead.

Comment: What do you pass as owner parameter to TKeywordFrame.Create ? If it is the tab sheet, go with @RM's answer. Otherwise with Uwe Raabe's answer. Don't forget that you must typecast AOwner to TTabSheet so you can access the Caption property.

Answer (score 0):

Self.Parent was the right direction. Thanks RM.

```
procedure TKeywordFrame.KeywordNameEditKeyPress( Sender : TObject; var Key : Char );
  var
    AOwner : TWinControl;

  begin
    if( ord( Key ) = VK_RETURN ) then
      begin
        AOwner := Self.Parent;

        FKeywordListName := KeywordNameEdit.Text;

          if( AOwner is TTabSheet ) then
            begin
              TTabSheet( AOwner ).Caption := FKeywordListName;
            end;
      end;
  end;
```

It is interesting to note that Self.Parent points to TTabSheet not TFrame, as one would assume, as that is where the control resides.